# Data grid view won't update

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a datagrid and a refresh button. I want to refresh data when I click on it but it won't. I also deleted all the rows from SQL Server but the data is still there.

Here's my button code:

```
Student std = new Student();
dataGridView1.DataSource = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = std.List();
```

and here's is my `List()` function:

```
public DataTable List()
{
    try
    {
        sdl.Command.CommandText = this.GetType().Name + "_List";

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Clear();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sdl.Command);

        sda.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Message = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sdl.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sdl.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need below line

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Windows Forms, to refresh the datagrid contents, assuming that std.List() works and actually gets new data you could try:

```
 this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();             //end current edits if you allow this (optional)
 this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;     //reset datasource binding
 this.dataGridView1.DataSource = std.List();
```

This topic has been debated heavily in the past e.g. see:[Refresh dgv](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18a9762e-ac67-48a7-a372-55307fe344f3/how-do-you-refresh-data-bound-to-a-datagridview).

Answer (score 0):

```
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  ds.Tables.Add(List());

  DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```